# Auto Update Prices From Master List

Tags: javascript, php, html, database-design

I run a fairly basic website for the company I work for and up till now we've been content to use a PDF price list available for download from our website however some of our customers struggle to use it or even find it.

Taking this into account we would like to put the prices of products on each product page. This represents a lot of work to keep up to date as we have a lot of product pages, I don't mind setting this up initially but as prices increase, fluctuate or change I would prefer to only be updating the one page/file/database which the product pages then pull their prices from.

I have searched and searched for a way to do this but to no avail, hopefully asking directly myself will turn up a result!

Is is possible to have one central price list database that all the product pages pull their prices from? If so, what is the best way to go about this? Are there any common examples available for reference?

Thank you for your help in advance.

A

Comment: Use a database (I recommend using MySQL or PDO) to store everything : each product, with price, picture, description, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Alex,
    It would be helpful to know more about how your website is currently structured and what technologies you are currently using.

If I were starting from scratch, I would make a template product page with javascript that makes an `XMLHTTPRequest` to an api on the backend (php is the most common, nodejs is also great).  This backend api will make the calls to your database and return the values to the client in a JSON document where the js renders the page.

If you want to do server-side rendering, you once again have a template product page (PHP is the most common).  When the page is called, PHP then queries the database and puts together the HTML, then ships it to the client.

NEVER allow the client to interact with the database directly!